# how to get path to file from one action to another?

Tags: java

I have a little problem. I want to get path to the file from open Action and i want use it in save action and two another... The best for me will be save path to the string but i dont know how do this.
And this is my code:

```
final String pathmain;
        Action open = new AbstractAction("Open"){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                    "Pliki tekstowe txt", "txt");
                chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
                int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(getParent());
                if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                  // System.out.println("You chose to open this file: "+ chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
                  String path = chooser.getSelectedFile().toString();

                  try {
                    FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                    String s;
                    while((s = br.readLine()) !=null){
                        textarea.append(s+"\n");
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                }
            }
        };
        Action save = new AbstractAction("Save"){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                try {
                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("aaa.txt"));
                    String buffer = textarea.getText();
                    //FileWriter fw = new FileWriter((textarea.getText().toString()));
                    //textarea.write(pw);
                    out.write(buffer);
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the selected file in an attribute of the object defining these two actions.

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    private File selectedFile;

    public MyPanel() {
         Action open = new AbstractAction("Open") {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 ...
                 selectedFile = ...
             }
         };
         ...
    } 
}
```

Comment: Ok, so now i have smth like here:
http://pastebin.com/FeDHK5DH
And it gives me error:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @Blackchart thats because you have not initialized `File selected` instance. This might help you [---> How To Get The Filepath Of A File In Java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-the-filepath-of-a-file-in-java/)

Comment: Ok so what is now wrong? I want to fix it but it's still dont want to work :(
http://pastebin.com/pJu1LM6d
What interesting in debuger i can see that path is corect ..

Comment: @Blackchart First take a look at link I provided in previous comment and understand it, Secondly in your code you have `path` declared as `File` as well as `String`